# Extract Multiple Values from Option element and POST

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm completely new to the world of JavaScript/JSON and could do with a set of experienced eyes to take a look at what i have so far and what I'm missing.

I need to be able to extract 2 values from an option value tag and be able to reference them individually in a JSON request.

So far i have the below:

HTML

```
<select name="selectName" id="selectId">
    <option value="1111,test">Test
</select>`
```

POST

```
var selectName = $('#selectId').val();

$('#selectId').value.split(',');

$('firstValue').val('selectName[0]);

$('secondValue').val('selectName[1]);

function postName() {

    $.post("url", {field1: $('firstValue').val(), field2: $('secondValue').val()}, function(response) {
    //alert(response);
 });
}
```

As mentioned I'm pretty new to this type of coding and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: `<select>` elements can only have a single value. What do you expect `firstValue` and `secondValue` to equal?

Comment: I had done some research and found that you can create an array within the value tag which could then be split with Java, so my expectation is that firstValue will equal the first string of my value (1111) and the secondValue will be the second (test)

Comment: Java != Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues with your code.

You're confusing jQuery selectors with variables. The following will take the selected value of `#selectId`, and split it into an array. Then we can access that array inside of the `post()` function:

```
var selectName = $('#selectId').val(),
    values     = selectName.split(',');

// No need to wrap $.post in a function here:
$.post("url", { field1: values[0], field2: values[1] }, function(response) {
    // alert(response);
});
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks for taking the time to answer the bits that were confusing, i'll give this a go and let you know how i get on!

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work, the alert doesn't show me the values that we're passing

Comment: Why would the alert show you the values that you're passing? It should show the server's response.

Comment: Sorry, wrong choice of words, i had meant that when i've tried to alert the variables (not the response) it doesn't show the value for the select option i've submitted

Comment: Can you please put together a working example in jsFiddle. It's unclear what exactly you're doing, and how you're calling the function.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the assist, i've found a different method that allows me to store the value in another input field, i've then be able to reference that input field for my JSON post. This helped massively though so thank you!